# cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘const class mysqlpp::String’

Tags: c++, mysql, variables, type-conversion, gtk3

I need to retrieve an INT from a database (MariaDB) and put it in a list made with GTK3.

When I try to pass the variable from MariaDB to GTK3, the compiler throws the following error:

`cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘const class mysqlpp::String’ through ‘...’`
(This happens in the function `void item(string nombre)`, in the lines inside the brackets, in the for loop)

So, I would thank to anyone who can tell me a way to fix this problem.
Thank you for your answers.

The code is the one following:

```
void item(string nombre)
{
    Connection con;
    con.connect("", server, user, pass);
    con.select_db(db);

    string consulta = nombre;

    Query pedido = con.query(consulta);
    StoreQueryResult resp = pedido.store();

    Row fila;
    for (i=0; i<resp.num_rows(); i++)
/*THE PROBLEM IS HERE*/    
        {
        gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &list_iterator);
        gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &list_iterator, 0, resp[i][1], 1, resp[i][2], 2, resp[i][1],-1);
        }

    con.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: And which line is line 70?

Comment: I know it's in there, but do you really expect us to *count* line 70 from the top of the source file? It's customary to add a comment on the line where the error occurs so that we don't have to hunt it down ourselves.

Comment: @cdhowie Its in void item(string nombre) its inside the brackets for (i=0; i<resp.num_rows(); i++) { gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &list_iterator); gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &list_iterator, 0, resp[i][1], 1, resp[i][2], 2, resp[i][1],-1); }

Comment: 70 and 71 are the lines inside the brackets in that part

Comment: After some time using SOF, now I feel more familiar with the way it works, so I changed the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass a `mysqlpp::String` object to `gtk_list_store_set()`.  You can't do this, because it is a C function and does not understand C++ objects.<sup>1</sup>

Instead, call `c_str()` on the string object, which returns a pointer to a null-terminated string.  `gtk_list_store_set()` will copy the value of the pointed-to string into its own internal structures, so there will be no data ownership issues.

```
gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &list_iterator,
                   0, resp[i][1].c_str(),
                   1, resp[i][2].c_str(),
                   2, resp[i][1].c_str(),
                   -1);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, you are trying to pass a C++ object in a `va_arg` structure, which is what `...` represents in the C function prototype.  You can only do this with so-called [*trivially-copyable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) objects, and `mysqlpp::String` objects are not trivially-copyable.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have been stucked with this for some time. 
I will have to look for this, because Im a newbie with all this, but for now IT WORKED :)